# `python3 bar.py` execute file without modifying mode

Tags: python

Suppose there's this script:

```
    #! /usr/local/bin/python3
    # I'm bar
    print('bar')
```

Check the file permissions:

```
    ls -l bar.py
    -rw-r--r--  1 me  staff  56 Mar 31 17:47 bar.py
```

Run it:

```
    $ python3 bar.py
    bar
    # the mode was not changed after being executed
    $ ls -l bar.py
    -rw-r--r--  1 me  staff  56 Mar 31 17:47 bar.py
```

However, if I execute it from the specified interpreter

```
    $ ./bar.py
    bash: ./bar.py: Permission denied
```

It means that the mode should've been modified previously.

```
    $ chmod 755 bar.py
    $ ./bar.py
    bar
```

What's the mechanism behind `python3 bar.py` which executes a file without amending mode?

Comment: In the first case, you execute `python3`, which is executable.

Comment: This is OS related more than python related

Comment: Running `python3 bar.py` is the same as running `nano spam.txt` or `pdfviewer eggs.pdf`. The fact that `python3` happens to be a Python interpreter instead of a text editor or a PDF viewer doesn't matter at all to Unix.

Comment: ty, I understand it in a ms. @abarnert

Comment: your bar.py is not a script. Even your script is not executable means a bash or shell script. Your have to run it with python appended.

Comment: I prefer the answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/136547/282899, could  you please redirect the dub   to this @ivan_pozdeev

Comment: How could I redirect the dub to https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/136547/282899 @Aran-Fey

Comment: @Tool We can't close your question as a duplicate of a question that's posted on a different site. I'm honestly not sure what to do with your question. I'm not sure if it's even on topic here on SO.